# Azure B2C - Sign-in with non-English email addresses

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We are using a custom sign-up/sign-in policy with Azure B2C and are having trouble trying to sign-in with foreign language email addresses.

We have followed the Microsoft tutorials and have used the custom starter XML files [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/LocalAccounts).

We initially found that we couldn't even SIGN-UP with a foreign language email address (such as 伊伊伊伊伊伊伊@伊伊伊.伊伊伊) but we noticed that there was some regex in the TrustFrameworkBase.xml starter file that we could manipulate:

```
  <ClaimType Id="email">
    <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="email" />
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <UserHelpText>Email address that can be used to contact you.</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
    <Restriction>
      <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" HelpText="Please enter a valid email address." />
    </Restriction>
  </ClaimType>
```

So we changed the regular expression and we could sign-up!

But then, when we tried to sign-IN with the account we just signed-up with we got a message saying "Please enter a valid email address".

I've tried this with a vanilla sign-up/sign-in policy out-the-box and I get the same thing. There's a regex pattern attribute on the HTML text box that looks like:

```
      <input type="email" id="logonIdentifier" name="Username or email address" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;’'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" placeholder="Email Address" value="" tabindex="1">
```

that prevents sign-in.

If I go in and remove this pattern regex I can actually sign-in, so I know it CAN work. I just need to remove this pattern attribute.

I must be missing something. Can anyone tell me what I need to configure to be able to sign-in with such an email address?

Comment: Do you receive a specific error message when you try to sign up? If so, I can follow up with the product team to see why this is the case.

Comment: Sign-up is fine actually! I can edit the TrustFrameworkBase.xml file and change the regex to whatever I want. But I just can't find  where to remove the regex pattern from the sign IN page. I get a "Please Enter a Valid Email Address" message. I'v'e even edited the HTML to remove this regex and I can then sign-in! So, all I need is to find a way of removing this regex on sign-in. Then everything would work.

Comment: You can try putting in explicit regex for "signinname" claims. Just copy the Restriction xml element from email claim to "signinname" claim.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but it has no effect - as if the restriction XML is simply ignored. I've since been in touch with Microsoft support who are saying that it's an issue that they are looking into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The email regex pattern for signIn is not pulled from "pattern" attribute in ClaimType from policy. That's why you are observing this behavior.

What you can do is by adding a language setting in technical profile metadata like following.

```
   <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
      <Metadata>

        ...
        <Item Key="language.email_pattern">{desired_pattern}</Item>
      </Metadata>
      ….
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: You sir, are an absolute legend. I would never have worked this out. How did you know???

Comment: @IainMcKinley he is from Redmond so he apparently works @ Microsoft.